# RCTUIManager.m Error frame is not a descendant of <RCTShadowView> IOS

Tags: react-native

I'm having this error when I toggle text input and while the keyboard is being shown. The text input is inside an animated.view which I present modally.

```
[error][tid:com.facebook.react.ShadowQueue][RCTUIManager.m:1188] view <RCTShadowView: 0x1284daae0; viewName: RCTTextField; reactTag: 318; frame: {{0, 27.5}, {256, 18}}> (tag #318) is not a descendant of <RCTShadowView: 0x12827bd40; viewName: RCTView; reactTag: 256; frame: {{0, 0}, {320, 799}}> (tag #256)
```

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem**

The main cause of this error, I've found, is when multiple views are listening to the keyboard at the same time.  This can happen, for example, when multiple scroll views inside a navigation stack are listening to keyboard events in order to scroll to a text input.  This issue has come up several times with [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view), when users of the library push multiple scroll views onto the same navigation stack.

This is a known issue within RN.  You might find the discussion around this PR helpful:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/7876

**Current Solution**

I don't know exactly what your use case is, but the solution is to make sure that you don't have multiple views listening to the keyboard at the same time.  You can do this by either registering and unregistering Keyboard event listeners at appropriate times, or (in the case I described above, where the problem is caused by multiple keyboard aware scroll views in a navigation stack), removing any views that subscribe to keyboard events from the navigation stack before pushing a new view.

As you can see from the PR above, fixing this problem might get a lot easier soon.  But in the meantime, you can just manually check for how many listeners you have on the keyboard.

Comment: Can you please explain more detailed how to manually check keyboard listeners?